# Youtube Oauth callback not working

Tags: java, http, rest, oauth, youtube

I am using an URL like the following:

```
  https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken?
oauth_token=ab3cd9j4ks73hf7g&oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com
```

This gets redirected to:

```
http://www.youtube.com/oauth_authorize_token?oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&oauth_token=1%2FyT-RZ-5PAMCp43Wt0RAGpNUAbMKAHxq1MG_RiX3Cmtk
```

After the user clicks allow access, YouTube directs the page to:

```
http://www.youtube.com/t/oauth_token_authorized
```

Why is the callback not working?

Their [API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth.html) seems to agree with what I am doing.

Comment: Same problem here... YouTube keeps on redirecting me to that page stevebot mentioned without returning an authorized access token! I've read that this has already been a problem somewhen in 2009. I posted the problem in the YouTube APIs Developer Forum: http://groups.google.com/group/youtube-api-gdata/browse_thread/thread/624053b218803eec

Comment: I ran into the same problem while playing with the example code from [OAuthExample.java](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/trunk/java/sample/oauth/OAuthExample.java). I have also posted a question on YouTube forum, hopefully it will be sorted out soon.

Comment: @maetty So far the best response I've received from them is to use OAuth 2.0 which is still in development :/

Comment: which OAuth tool do you use? I used Spring Security OAuth, was working fine for me. quite easy to configure

Comment: @javagirl I might have to give that a try, so far I've been using either Scribe or Google's own client.

Comment: http://term.ie/oauth/example/ also I used it for testing tokens etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In sum, you're specifying the oauth_callback too late in the process. Instead, provide it at the very beginning. For Google's provider, that's when you're calling OAuthGetRequestToken.

[This Google documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth.html#tokensCallback) seems to get it right. Strange. I also found [other documentation](http://wiki.oauth.net/w/page/12238555/Signed%20Callback%20URLs) that explains the same thing: "The [Service Provider] MUST associate the callback URL sent in Step 1 with the request token it issues."  So, you have to provide the callback URL when getting the "unauthorized" request token ("unauthorized" because the user hasn't given their permission yet). After you've done this, you can forward the user to the Authorization URL, where the user (aka resource owner) grants access explicitly for your application.

[Here's a page](http://hueniverse.com/2011/06/oauth-2-0-redirection-uri-validation/) that gives related information about OAuth 2.0.

Comment: Thanks! There is a thread about the bug you mention currently on the YouTube Developer API forums, so hopefully the fix their documentation.